# C# - How to create a DataTable from a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I have a dictionary of statistic values which basically looks like this:

```
Dictionary<StatisticsType, List<Value>>
```

`StatisticsType` is an enum which consists of flags like Minimum, Maximum, StdDev, Count and so on.
Here is a very simplified version of the `Value` class:

```
public class Value
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to write this data to a SQL Server database using a `SqlBulkCopy` object. To do so I need to create a `DataTable` which contains the data from the dictionary like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
returnValue.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(DateTime));
returnValue.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(double));
returnValue.Columns.Add("Minimum", typeof(double));
returnValue.Columns.Add("Maximum", typeof(double));
returnValue.Columns.Add("Average", typeof(double));
returnValue.Columns.Add("StdDev", typeof(double));
```

Usually for every timestamp there will be exactly one value in each of the lists in the dictionary so I need to find the next timestamp (maybe from the first list in the dictionary?), read the statistic value with this timestamp from each of the lists and then put those in one row of the table. What would be the best way to get the data from the dictionary into this table? I cannot simply create a new row for each value in the dictionary because each row needs to contain all of the statistic values for a certain timestamp.

Comment: @PeterB I added the class to my question. I am not really sure how to show some representative data here. How should I visualize that?

Comment: You can represent example data through code using something like this - format it in your code editor to make it more readable: `var data = new Dictionary<StatisticsType, List<Value>> { { StatisticsType.Minimum, new List<Value> { new Value { T = t1, V = 7 }, new Value { T = t2, V = 8 }, new Value { T = t3, V = 10 } } }, { StatisticsType.Maximum, new List<Value> { new Value { T = t1, V = 13 }, new Value { T = t2, V = 12 }, new Value { T = t3, V = 14 } } } };`

Comment: Note - I had to rename the `Value` property to `V` because I couldn't give a property the same name as its class. Then also renamed `Timestamp` to `T` for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(double));
            table.Columns.Add("Minimum", typeof(double));
            table.Columns.Add("Maximum", typeof(double));
            table.Columns.Add("Average", typeof(double));
            table.Columns.Add("StdDev", typeof(double));

            Dictionary<StatisticsType, List<Value>> dict = new Dictionary<StatisticsType, List<Value>>();

            foreach(KeyValuePair<StatisticsType, List<Value>> row in dict)
            {
                double average = row.Value.Average(x => x.Value);
                double sumOfSquaresOfDifferences = row.Value.Select(val => (val.Value - average) * (val.Value - average)).Sum();
                double sd = Math.Sqrt(sumOfSquaresOfDifferences / row.Value.Count());

                table.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    row.Key.ToString(),
                    row.Value.First().Timestamp,
                    row.Value.Count(),
                    row.Value.Min(x => x.Value),
                    row.Value.Max(x => x.Value),
                    average,
                    sd});
            }
        }
    }
    public enum StatisticsType
    {
        Minimum, 
        Maximum, 
        StdDev, 
        Count 
    }
    public class Value
    {
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }
```